# How do I go down a binary tree using questions?

Tags: java, binary-tree

I'm trying to set up a binary tree to do the following:

- If I write Y, it will print the left child. If I write N, it will
  print the right child.

  ```
  UI.println("Is it true: " + node + "(Y/N)");
  ```
- If it is just a leaf node, it will just write the answer.

  ```
  UI.println(node);
  ```

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble with?

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out how to do it. I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague but in general you do this as follows:
Write a function that takes as argument a node from the tree and asks the question. If the node is a leaf then the function prints the node and returns. Otherwise it asks the question and depending on the answer the function recursively calls itself either on the left or the right child of the node.

Initially the function is invoked with the tree's root node as argument.

Note that for very high trees, this recursive approach may result in a stack overflow. So if you expect high trees you may want to unroll the recursion to a simple loop.